# Pointer value in c

Tags: c

Generally speaking, a pointer's value inside a function in c is local or can be accessed in main through the pointer?

Example code:

```
size_t *function(int a, int *b)
{   
    int d;
    size_t *array;
    b = &d;
    //DO STUFF HERE
    printf("%d", *b); //This gets printed right
    return array;

  }
int main()
{
    size_t *array2;
    int *b;

    array2 = function(a, b);
    printf("%d", *b);   //This gives seg fault

}
```

Comment: Note that if the actual question was how to get the value of `d` to to `main` without returning it, you could have `int d` in `main` and pass `&d` as argument, then you can assign to `main`'s `d` as `*b = d` in `function`.

Comment: Slightly OT: you return the uninitialized (and unused) pointer `array` from function, which is pretty pointless

Comment: I was assuming the `DO STUFF HERE` part actually allocates the array and assigns a value to `d`, but if not, then that's indeed another problem.

Comment: exactly! DO STUFF HERE does stuff to the array and assigns value to d

Comment: @arkku you are genius! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are local variables, so you are not actually assigning to `main`'s pointer, you are just ignoring the value passed as argument and assigning to the local `b` in `function`. You need a pointer to pointer `int **b` argument in order to assign to the `b` in `main`.

Also, the assigned address is that of a local variable `d`, which ceases to exist when `function` returns so accessing it afterwards through a pointer would be invalid regardless (undefined behaviour, even if it might happen to work before it gets overwritten on the stack).

edit: If your goal is to get the *value* of `d` to `main`, you don't need a pointer in `main`, so instead of `b` you can have `int d` in `main` and pass its address `&d` to `function` (`function(a, &d)`), then you can assign to `main`'s `d` in `function` with `*b = d`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck in this for hours

Answer (score 0):

In function *main* you pass the pointer *b* to *function* but *b* is uninitialized (can contain any value):

```
array2 = function(a, b);
```

Thefore this makes no sense. Inside *function*, If you want to modify *b* you need to instead call *function* like this:

```
int b;

array2 = function(a, &b);
```

The function can now assign to **b*.

Answer (score 0):

As Arkku says Arguments are local variables, you can treat the pointer as an address value like 0x7fff13f1ce3c, then it's pretty easy to understand.

```c
typedef address int*
typedef address2 size_t*

size_t *function(int a, address b)
{   
    int d;
    address2 array;
    b = &d;
    //DO STUFF HERE
    printf("%d", *b); //This gets printed right
    return array;

  }
int main()
{
    address2 array2;
    address b;

    array2 = function(a, b);
    printf("%d", *b);   //This gives seg fault

}
```

Change the value of b in `function` won't influence the value of b in `main`. As for the array, `function` will return An address value.